# Jquery next() for a gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm creating a kind of lightbox gallery by myself but I have problem with loading next and previous images
`$("a.lightbox").click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this).next().attr('href');
    alert(a);
  });`
As you see this thing doesn't work and I need the href contain of the next element.My HTML is something like this:

```
<ul class="listing">
        <li><a href="imgs/eli.jpg" id="1" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/eli_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/ggallin.jpg" id="2" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/ggallin_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/jontarata.jpg" id="3" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/jontarata_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/macka s tatuirovki.jpg" id="4" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/macka s tatuirovki_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/mk7.jpg" id="5" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/mk7_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/P5010345.jpg" id="6" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/P5010345_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `next` on your `a` element. There are no elements that are after your `a` tag. You could first get the parent, get the next `li` and then grab the `a` from its children.

```
var a = $(this).parent().next().children('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: and how to pass this variable to a different function?

Comment: As a parameter? Not sure I understand what you want.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var a = $(this).parent().next().children('a').attr('href');
```

You have to navigate up to the parent, move to the next `li` and then get the link.

You'll also want to add logic in to deal with reaching the end (and beginning) of the list.