# Jquery parameters passing between functions

Tags: javascript, gallery, image-gallery

I need to pass the 2 variables(nextimage, previmage) in this function

```
$("a.lightbox").click(function abc(e) {
    var nextimage = $(this).parent().next().children('a').attr('href');
    var previmage = $(this).parent().prev().children('a').attr('href');
    return nextimage;
    return previmage;
});
```

They should be passed to this function like

```
function nextimage(){
    $('<img src="nextimage"/>')
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand.

Comment: I need to pass the 2 variables from function abc() to function nextimage()

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How do you return something from a click event? Who would catch the returned values? Why not just call `nextimage()` from within the handler?

Comment: Leave out the code for now. What are you trying to do? Functionally.

Comment: Within the handler any source cause I'm some kind of a newbie

Comment: Catch which link is clicked get the previous and next sources of images and load this images calling them inside nextimage() function

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for..

```
$("a.lightbox").click(function(e) {
    var nextimage = $(this).parent().next().children('a').attr('href');
    var previmage = $(this).parent().prev().children('a').attr('href');

    nextimage(nextimage, previmage);
});


function nextimage(nextimage, previmage){
    $('<img src="nextimage"/>')
}
```

Though the function call may not be necessary...depending on your application.

Comment: I should pass nextimage to the function nextimage

Comment: I simply named the function after your original post. If you could give me more information on the purpose of the function currently named "nextimage", I could help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I got better solution. Check this:

Ref: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599079/jquery-next-for-a-gallery)

```
<div>
<ul class="listing">
        <li><a href="imgs/eli.jpg" id="1" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/eli_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/ggallin.jpg" id="2" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/ggallin_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/jontarata.jpg" id="3" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/jontarata_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/macka s tatuirovki.jpg" id="4" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/macka s tatuirovki_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/mk7.jpg" id="5" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/mk7_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="imgs/P5010345.jpg" id="6" class="lightbox"><img src="thumbs/P5010345_t.jpg" width="150" height="100" class="images" /></a></li>
    </ul>
<a id="prev">Prev</a>
<a id="next">Next</a>
</div>
<img id="currentImage"></img>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var showImage = function(i) { 
        var url = $("ul.listing a").eq(i).attr("href"); 

        $("#currentImage").attr("src", url);
        index = i;
    };
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        showImage(index - 1);
    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        showImage(index + 1);
    });

    $("ul.listing a").click(function() { var i = $(this).index(); showImage(i); });
})();
</script>
```